# Как работает NPM модуль request-promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, request, promise

Подключил модуль request-promise. Для отправки файла использую вот такой код. Код написал схематично, что бы было понятен вопрос.

```js
let requestInstance = request.post({uri: uri, json: true});

requestInstance
  .then(function(response) {
    // Успешный ответ сервера
    res.json(response);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // На сервере что-то пошло не так
    res.status(500).json({message: 'some error'});
  });

// А вот самое интересное!!!
let form = requestInstance.form();
let i = 0;

req.files.forEach(f => {
  form.append('f_' + i, f.buffer, {
    filename: f.originalname,
    encoding: f.encoding,
    mimetype: f.mimetype,
    size: f.size
  });
  
  i++;
});

// И все!
```

Что-то не понимаю, как работает этот код. Нет, что он работает правильно это хорошо, вопрос как?

Я делаю запрос к серверу или скорее предзапрос, который мне возвращает промис. Далее я в цикле прикрепляю файлы. И все. Где метод, который начинает отправку данных на сервер? Ведь я нигде не вызываю метод start, send, run и прочее. Где эта начальная точка?

Может я неправильно понимаю суть POST запроса :(

Comment: у вас асинхронный код выполниться после цикла по `req.files.forEach`, где перебираются все выбранные файлы и добавляются в форму запроса, после этого уже обработается `requestInstance` вернув ответ с сервера. На самом деле странный пример

Comment: to Василий Барбашев. Т.е как понимаю здесь происходит неявный вызов команды send. Т.е сформировали объект запроса, вернули промис, а потом через setImmediate или setTimeout вызвали send. Нда... Оно конечно прикольно. Разработчик наверное думал, что так прикольнее, и не подумал о других.

Comment: Что касается странности примера, то так в доке к модулю написано.

Comment: Тут скорее метод `append` добавляет в форму данные, а обработчик видит, что ещё не все данные обработались и дожидается этого, после чего вызовется метод `then`. По сути `append` это ваш `send`

Comment: Тогда вопрос - каким образом обработчик понимает, что все?

Comment: он смотрит что в форме есть недогруженные элементы, можно сказать он делает список промисов. Когда промисы все завершатся вызывается конечный метод подписки, и говорит что все было обработано.